# Recursively parse XML to create JSON array using dataweave 2

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I am trying to parse an XML recursively to create JSON array using dataweave 2 but I am not able to do so.

My Input XML is given below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
    <Header>
        <MessageId>{8736346D-A766-4BE1-8592-C263A4CC2AB5}</MessageId>
        <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/BomBillsofMaterialsService/read</Action>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
            <BillsOfMaterials xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BillsOfMaterials">
                <DocPurpose>Original</DocPurpose>
                <SenderId>121</SenderId>
                <BOMVersion class="entity">
                    <_DocumentHash>5c32768c0e32d542255d67340fda7a9d</_DocumentHash>
                    <Active>Yes</Active>
                    <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                    <Approver>NoUser</Approver>
                    <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                    <Construction>No</Construction>
                    <InventDimId>IDM0000001</InventDimId>
                    <ItemId>9641716</ItemId>
                    <ItemIdCommercial/>
                    <Name>Prepress Bundle - Folding Carton</Name>
                    <QBE_AddedByContainer>Yes</QBE_AddedByContainer>
                    <RecId>5637161354</RecId>
                    <RecVersion>1034011536</RecVersion>
                    <BOMTable class="entity">
                        <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                        <Approver>NoUser</Approver>
                        <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                        <CheckBOM>Yes</CheckBOM>
                        <Name>Prepress Bundle - Folding Carton</Name>
                        <RecId>5637160605</RecId>
                        <RecVersion>450200996</RecVersion>
                        <SiteId>2</SiteId>
                        <BOM class="entity">
                            <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                            <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                            <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                            <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                            <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                            <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                            <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000031</InventDimId>
                            <ItemId>96AR169X</ItemId>
                            <LineNum>1.0000000000</LineNum>
                            <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                            <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                            <RecId>5637300477</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                            <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                            <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                                <InventDimId>IDM0000031</InventDimId>
                                <InventLocationId>51ST</InventLocationId>
                                <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                                <RecId>5637213319</RecId>
                                <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            </InventDimBOM>
                            <BOMTable>
                                <BOMId>BOM011986</BOMId>
                                
                                <Name/>
                                <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>96AR060W</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>111111111</RecId>
                                </BOM>
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>2.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>96AR158</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>222222</RecId>
                                </BOM>
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>3.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>96AR582O</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>333333333</RecId>
                                    <BOMTable>
                                        <BOMId>BOM0013773</BOMId>
                                        <Name>ArtiosCAD 14 A6 Software box (Standard Edition)</Name>
                                        <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                        
                                        <BOM>
                                            <LineNum>1000.00</LineNum>
                                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                            <ItemId>G211249</ItemId>
                                            <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                            <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                            <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                            <RecId>4444444</RecId>
                                        </BOM>
                                        <BOM>
                                            <LineNum>1006.00</LineNum>
                                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                            <ItemId>G25583954_46</ItemId>
                                            <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                            <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                            <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                            <RecId>55555555</RecId>
                                        </BOM>
                                    </BOMTable>
                                    <BOMTable>
                                        <BOMId>BOM0013773</BOMId>
                                        <Name>ArtiosCAD 14 A6 Software box (Standard Edition)</Name>
                                        <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                        <RecId>333333333</RecId>
                                        <BOM>
                                            <LineNum>1000.00</LineNum>
                                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                            <ItemId>G211249</ItemId>
                                            <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                            <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                            <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                            <RecId>66666666</RecId>
                                        </BOM>
                                        <BOM>
                                            <LineNum>1006.00</LineNum>
                                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                            <ItemId>G25583954_46</ItemId>
                                            <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                            <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                            <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                            <RecId>77777777777</RecId>
                                        </BOM>
                                    </BOMTable>
                                </BOM>
                            </BOMTable>
                        </BOM>
                        <BOM class="entity">
                            <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                            <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                            <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                            <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                            <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                            <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                            <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                            <ItemId>9646095W</ItemId>
                            <LineNum>11.0000000000</LineNum>
                            <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                            <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                            <RecId>5637300487</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                            <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                            <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                                <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                                <InventLocationId>NOLOC</InventLocationId>
                                <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                                <RecId>5637213290</RecId>
                                <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            </InventDimBOM>
                        </BOM>
                        <BOM class="entity">
                            <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                            <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                            <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                            <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                            <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                            <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                            <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                            <ItemId>9648376X</ItemId>
                            <LineNum>12.0000000000</LineNum>
                            <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                            <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                            <RecId>5637300488</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                            <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                            <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                                <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                                <InventLocationId>NOLOC</InventLocationId>
                                <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                                <RecId>5637213290</RecId>
                                <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            </InventDimBOM>
                            <BOMTable>
                                <BOMId>BOM011638</BOMId>
                                <Name/>
                                <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>9645340X</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>888888888</RecId>
                                </BOM>
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>2.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>9644384Y</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>9999999999</RecId>
                                </BOM>
                            </BOMTable>
                        </BOM>
                        <BOM class="entity">
                            <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                            <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                            <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                            <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                            <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                            <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                            <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                            <ItemId>9643908X</ItemId>
                            <LineNum>13.0000000000</LineNum>
                            <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                            <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                            <RecId>5637300489</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                            <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                            <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                                <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                                <InventLocationId>01</InventLocationId>
                                <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                                <RecId>5637213291</RecId>
                                <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            </InventDimBOM>
                            <BOMTable>
                                <BOMId>BOM011299</BOMId>
                                <Name/>
                                <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                <RecId>555555555</RecId>
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>9642737Y</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>101010101</RecId>
                                </BOM>
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>3.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>9642736Y</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>1112112112</RecId>
                                </BOM>
                            </BOMTable>
                        </BOM>
                        <BOM class="entity">
                            <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                            <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                            <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                            <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                            <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                            <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                            <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                            <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                            <ItemId>9642837X</ItemId>
                            <LineNum>14.0000000000</LineNum>
                            <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                            <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                            <RecId>5637300490</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                            <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                            <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                            <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                                <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                                <InventLocationId>01</InventLocationId>
                                <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                                <RecId>5637213291</RecId>
                                <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                            </InventDimBOM>
                            <BOMTable>
                                <BOMId>BOM011245</BOMId>
                                <Name/>
                                <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                
                                <BOM>
                                    <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                    <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                    <ItemId>9644384Y</ItemId>
                                    <BOMQty>-1.00</BOMQty>
                                    <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                    <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                    <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                    <RecId>13131313</RecId>
                                </BOM>
                            </BOMTable>
                        </BOM>
                    </BOMTable>
                    <InventDim class="entity">
                        <InventDimId>IDM0000001</InventDimId>
                        <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                        <RecId>5637199988</RecId>
                        <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                    </InventDim>
                </BOMVersion>
            </BillsOfMaterials>
        </MessageParts>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I want to create JSON array of all the BOMs (a flat structure with no hierarchy) as shown below -

Output -

```
[
{
  "id": "5637300477",
  "productId": "96AR169X",
  "parentId": null     
},
{
  "id":  "111111111", 
  "productId":  "96AR060W", 
  "parentId" : "BOM011986" 
},
{
  "id":  "222222", 
  "productId":  "96AR158", 
  "parentId" : "BOM011986" 
},
{
  "id": "333333333",
  "productId": "96AR582O",
  "parentId": "BOM011986"    
},
{
  "id":  "4444444", 
  "productId":  "G211249", 
  "parentId" : "BOM0013773" 
},
{
  "id":  "55555555", 
  "productId":  "G25583954_46", 
  "parentId" : "BOM0013773" 
},
{
  "id":  "66666666", 
  "productId":  "BOM0013773", 
  "parentId" : "BOM0013773" 
},
{
  "id":  "77777777777", 
  "productId":  "G25583954_46", 
  "parentId" : "BOM0013773" 
},
{
  "id":  "5637300487", 
  "productId":  "9646095W", 
  "parentId" : null
},
{
  "id":  "5637300488", 
  "productId":  "9648376X", 
  "parentId" : null 
},
.

]
```

I not able to figure it out the use of recursion in this case.
I am quite new to Dataweave language as it is functional language. I am used to Java language.

Thanks in advance for help !!!

Comment: please clarify where id, productId and parentId come from for each level in the input.

Comment: It seems like the output does not relate properly to the given input. For example, item 96AR158 is under RecId "111111111" but output shows it is under "222222". As what aled have mentioned above, please clarify the mapping rules for the expected output.

Comment: id is being mapped with RecId inside BOM, productId is mapped to ItemId inside BOM and parentId is the RecId of the immediate RecId of the BOMTable.

Comment: Input corrected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of descendant data selector (using ..) to retrieve all BOMTable from your xml document and thus there is no need to recursively navigate through your document. Then using map/flatMap to output the necessary fields.

Please see below dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
  
payload..*BOMTable flatMap (bomTable) -> bomTable.*BOM map (bomValue) -> 
{
    id: bomValue.RecId,
    productId: bomValue.ItemId,
    parentId: bomTable.RecId
}
```

Output will be as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5637300477",
    "productId": "96AR169X",
    "parentId": "5637160605"
  },
  {
    "id": "5637300487",
    "productId": "9646095W",
    "parentId": "5637160605"
  },
  {
    "id": "5637300488",
    "productId": "9648376X",
    "parentId": "5637160605"
  },
  {
    "id": "5637300489",
    "productId": "9643908X",
    "parentId": "5637160605"
  },
  {
    "id": "5637300490",
    "productId": "9642837X",
    "parentId": "5637160605"
  },
  {
    "id": "111111111",
    "productId": "96AR060W",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "222222",
    "productId": "96AR158",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "333333333",
    "productId": "96AR582O",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "4444444",
    "productId": "G211249",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "55555555",
    "productId": "G25583954_46",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "66666666",
    "productId": "G211249",
    "parentId": "333333333"
  },
  {
    "id": "77777777777",
    "productId": "G25583954_46",
    "parentId": "333333333"
  },
  {
    "id": "888888888",
    "productId": "9645340X",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "9999999999",
    "productId": "9644384Y",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "101010101",
    "productId": "9642737Y",
    "parentId": "555555555"
  },
  {
    "id": "1112112112",
    "productId": "9642736Y",
    "parentId": "555555555"
  },
  {
    "id": "13131313",
    "productId": "9644384Y",
    "parentId": null
  }
]
```

Note that the output is still different from the expected output that you posted which I think is incorrect based on the mapping rules you posted in one of your comments.

Comment: Yes, it had issues but the concept you provided is sufficient for the solution. Thanks a ton !!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below dwl

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var payload = read('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
<Header>
    <MessageId>{8736346D-A766-4BE1-8592-C263A4CC2AB5}</MessageId>
    <Action>http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/BomBillsofMaterialsService/read</Action>
</Header>
<Body>
    <MessageParts xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2011/01/documents/Message">
        <BillsOfMaterials xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/BillsOfMaterials">
            <DocPurpose>Original</DocPurpose>
            <SenderId>121</SenderId>
            <BOMVersion class="entity">
                <_DocumentHash>5c32768c0e32d542255d67340fda7a9d</_DocumentHash>
                <Active>Yes</Active>
                <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                <Approver>NoUser</Approver>
                <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                <Construction>No</Construction>
                <InventDimId>IDM0000001</InventDimId>
                <ItemId>9641716</ItemId>
                <ItemIdCommercial/>
                <Name>Prepress Bundle - Folding Carton</Name>
                <QBE_AddedByContainer>Yes</QBE_AddedByContainer>
                <RecId>5637161354</RecId>
                <RecVersion>1034011536</RecVersion>
                <BOMTable class="entity">
                    <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                    <Approver>NoUser</Approver>
                    <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                    <CheckBOM>Yes</CheckBOM>
                    <Name>Prepress Bundle - Folding Carton</Name>
                    <RecId>5637160605</RecId>
                    <RecVersion>450200996</RecVersion>
                    <SiteId>2</SiteId>
                    <BOM class="entity">
                        <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                        <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                        <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                        <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                        <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                        <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                        <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                        <InventDimId>IDM0000031</InventDimId>
                        <ItemId>96AR169X</ItemId>
                        <LineNum>1.0000000000</LineNum>
                        <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                        <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                        <RecId>5637300477</RecId>
                        <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                        <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                        <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000031</InventDimId>
                            <InventLocationId>51ST</InventLocationId>
                            <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                            <RecId>5637213319</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        </InventDimBOM>
                        <BOMTable>
                            <BOMId>BOM011986</BOMId>
                            
                            <Name/>
                            <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>96AR060W</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>111111111</RecId>
                            </BOM>
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>2.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>96AR158</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>222222</RecId>
                            </BOM>
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>3.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>96AR582O</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>333333333</RecId>
                                <BOMTable>
                                    <BOMId>BOM0013773</BOMId>
                                    <Name>ArtiosCAD 14 A6 Software box (Standard Edition)</Name>
                                    <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                    
                                    <BOM>
                                        <LineNum>1000.00</LineNum>
                                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                        <ItemId>G211249</ItemId>
                                        <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                        <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                        <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                        <RecId>4444444</RecId>
                                    </BOM>
                                    <BOM>
                                        <LineNum>1006.00</LineNum>
                                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                        <ItemId>G25583954_46</ItemId>
                                        <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                        <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                        <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                        <RecId>55555555</RecId>
                                    </BOM>
                                </BOMTable>
                                <BOMTable>
                                    <BOMId>BOM0013773</BOMId>
                                    <Name>ArtiosCAD 14 A6 Software box (Standard Edition)</Name>
                                    <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                                    <RecId>333333333</RecId>
                                    <BOM>
                                        <LineNum>1000.00</LineNum>
                                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                        <ItemId>G211249</ItemId>
                                        <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                        <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                        <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                        <RecId>66666666</RecId>
                                    </BOM>
                                    <BOM>
                                        <LineNum>1006.00</LineNum>
                                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                        <ItemId>G25583954_46</ItemId>
                                        <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                        <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                        <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                        <RecId>77777777777</RecId>
                                    </BOM>
                                </BOMTable>
                            </BOM>
                        </BOMTable>
                    </BOM>
                    <BOM class="entity">
                        <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                        <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                        <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                        <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                        <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                        <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                        <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                        <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                        <ItemId>9646095W</ItemId>
                        <LineNum>11.0000000000</LineNum>
                        <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                        <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                        <RecId>5637300487</RecId>
                        <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                        <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                        <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                            <InventLocationId>NOLOC</InventLocationId>
                            <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                            <RecId>5637213290</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        </InventDimBOM>
                    </BOM>
                    <BOM class="entity">
                        <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                        <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                        <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                        <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                        <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                        <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                        <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                        <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                        <ItemId>9648376X</ItemId>
                        <LineNum>12.0000000000</LineNum>
                        <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                        <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                        <RecId>5637300488</RecId>
                        <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                        <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                        <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000002</InventDimId>
                            <InventLocationId>NOLOC</InventLocationId>
                            <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                            <RecId>5637213290</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        </InventDimBOM>
                        <BOMTable>
                            <BOMId>BOM011638</BOMId>
                            <Name/>
                            <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                            
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>9645340X</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>888888888</RecId>
                            </BOM>
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>2.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>9644384Y</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>9999999999</RecId>
                            </BOM>
                        </BOMTable>
                    </BOM>
                    <BOM class="entity">
                        <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                        <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                        <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                        <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                        <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                        <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                        <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                        <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                        <ItemId>9643908X</ItemId>
                        <LineNum>13.0000000000</LineNum>
                        <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                        <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                        <RecId>5637300489</RecId>
                        <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                        <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                        <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                            <InventLocationId>01</InventLocationId>
                            <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                            <RecId>5637213291</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        </InventDimBOM>
                        <BOMTable>
                            <BOMId>BOM011299</BOMId>
                            <Name/>
                            <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                            <RecId>555555555</RecId>
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>9642737Y</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>101010101</RecId>
                            </BOM>
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>3.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>9642736Y</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>1112112112</RecId>
                            </BOM>
                        </BOMTable>
                    </BOM>
                    <BOM class="entity">
                        <BOMConsump>Variable</BOMConsump>
                        <BOMId>BOM0012610</BOMId>
                        <BOMQty>1.0000</BOMQty>
                        <BOMQtySerie>1</BOMQtySerie>
                        <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                        <Calculation>Yes</Calculation>
                        <EndSchedConsump>No</EndSchedConsump>
                        <Formula>Formula0</Formula>
                        <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                        <ItemId>9642837X</ItemId>
                        <LineNum>14.0000000000</LineNum>
                        <ProdFlushingPrincip>Blank</ProdFlushingPrincip>
                        <ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>No</ProjSetSubProdToConsumed>
                        <RecId>5637300490</RecId>
                        <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        <RoundUp>No</RoundUp>
                        <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                        <WrkCtrConsumption>false</WrkCtrConsumption>
                        <InventDimBOM class="entity">
                            <InventDimId>IDM0000003</InventDimId>
                            <InventLocationId>01</InventLocationId>
                            <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                            <RecId>5637213291</RecId>
                            <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                        </InventDimBOM>
                        <BOMTable>
                            <BOMId>BOM011245</BOMId>
                            <Name/>
                            <Approved>Yes</Approved>
                            
                            <BOM>
                                <LineNum>1.00</LineNum>
                                <BOMType>Item</BOMType>
                                <ItemId>9644384Y</ItemId>
                                <BOMQty>-1.00</BOMQty>
                                <OprNum>0</OprNum>
                                <FromDate>1900-01-01</FromDate>
                                <UnitId>PCS</UnitId>
                                <RecId>13131313</RecId>
                            </BOM>
                        </BOMTable>
                    </BOM>
                </BOMTable>
                <InventDim class="entity">
                    <InventDimId>IDM0000001</InventDimId>
                    <InventSiteId>2</InventSiteId>
                    <RecId>5637199988</RecId>
                    <RecVersion>1</RecVersion>
                </InventDim>
            </BOMVersion>
        </BillsOfMaterials>
    </MessageParts>
</Body>
</Envelope>',"application/xml")
 ---
flatten((payload.Envelope.Body.MessageParts.BillsOfMaterials.BOMVersion..*BOMTable map 
{
 BOMTable : $.*BOM map (val) -> {
    "id": val.RecId,
    "productId": val.ItemId, 
    parentId : $.RecId
}
}).*BOMTable)
```

Output is

```
[
{
"id": "5637300477",
"productId": "96AR169X",
"parentId": "5637160605"
},
{
"id": "5637300487",
"productId": "9646095W",
"parentId": "5637160605"
},
{
"id": "5637300488",
"productId": "9648376X",
"parentId": "5637160605"
},
{
"id": "5637300489",
"productId": "9643908X",
"parentId": "5637160605"
},
{
"id": "5637300490",
"productId": "9642837X",
"parentId": "5637160605"
},
{
"id": "111111111",
"productId": "96AR060W",
"parentId": null
},
{
"id": "222222",
"productId": "96AR158",
"parentId": null
},
{
"id": "333333333",
"productId": "96AR582O",
"parentId": null
},
{
"id": "4444444",
"productId": "G211249",
"parentId": null
},
{
"id": "55555555",
"productId": "G25583954_46",
"parentId": null
},
{
"id": "66666666",
"productId": "G211249",
"parentId": "333333333"
},
{
"id": "77777777777",
"productId": "G25583954_46",
"parentId": "333333333"
},
{
"id": "888888888",
"productId": "9645340X",
"parentId": null
},
{
"id": "9999999999",
"productId": "9644384Y",
"parentId": null
},
{
"id": "101010101",
"productId": "9642737Y",
"parentId": "555555555"
},
{
"id": "1112112112",
"productId": "9642736Y",
"parentId": "555555555"
},
{
"id": "13131313",
"productId": "9644384Y",
"parentId": null
}
]
```

Comment: From Review : You have a solution and if there are other answers you should explain why your answer will work differently comparing to other.